# Reading NLog.config from NLog in API REST .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, nlog

I have a problem reading the configuration file (NLog.config) from my class library project when I call it from my ASP.NET MVC4 project.

I tested my code using an Unit Test Project and reads the configuration file properly and makes logging correctly on the file that I specified on the NLog.config, so the NLog.config is correctly defined.

I also set "Copy always" at Copy to Output Directory settings, just like the tutorial says.

The problem is that when I called the class library project, from my ASP project, I realized that wasn't making any kind of log, and when I debugged, I saw that It wasn't picking the configuration from NLog.config, and for that reason, my project didn't know when and where to log.

When I looked into "ASP project folder"/bin, there are the files from NLog: NLog.dll, NLog.config and NLog.xml, so in theory, the ASP project, can access without problem to the NLog files.

I read the tutorial from NLog but I can't figured out the solution. Just can´t understand why from my test project works properly but when I make the same call from my ASP project just don't work.

This is my configuration file for NLog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog throwExceptions="true" 
  xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<targets>
  <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\logfile.txt" layout="${callsite:fileName=true} - ${longdate} - ${level:uppercase=true} - ${logger} - ${message}"/>
</targets>

<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
</rules>
</nlog>
```

And within my classes, I create the logger this way:

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution.

Seems like with the copy to output directory setting, isn't enough with asp.net-mvc4.

[image: Copy to output directory]

I had to manually copy the NLog.config into the asp project itself inside the Solution explorer.

[Project explorer http://imageshack.us/a/img849/2460/sol1o.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img849/2460/sol1o.png)

In this example, I copied the NLog.config from LoggingLibrary into LogWebApp project and It works well.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on [internal logging](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Internal_logging) of nlog itself to see what it might tell you.

```
<nlog internalLogFile="c:\log.txt" internalLogLevel="Trace">
```

You might find it's a rights issue.

Comment: I did just that, but for the same reason that can't read the configuration file from my ASP project, can't read internalLogFile parameter from there. In my test project It makes internal logging, but I didn't see anything weird.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: do you use any LayoutRenderers?

Comment: I use the ones that you see at the NLog.config file that I described.

Comment: can you try without first, say just printing message.  Are any of these custom ones that you need to register on application start?

Comment: I try quitting all Layout parameters from configuration file but the problem remains. - I mean, removing the layout attribute.

Comment: can you try with just layout="${message}"

Comment: Yes, but seems that there are no difference