# NLog - I want to use NLog.config rather than App.config

Tags: nlog

On oppose to documentation, C# Application does not read NLog.config

(But In App.config, 'nlog' section is well read.)

So, Target and Rule is not working.

Comment: [This][1] stackoverflow question may help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469474/reading-nlog-config-from-nlog-in-api-rest-net

Comment: Thanks to your help. Though I don't know why it works, But Good working.